# Google Consumer Surveys Publishers Reporting Dashboard?

Tags: adsense, survey

I'm actually a bit embarrassed to be asking this question since it seems like such a simple thing but here goes:

I've recently signed up with Google Consumer Surveys and want to take advantage of their survey monetizing and become a survey publisher. We had an existing adsense account and applied to become a survey publisher. Eventually we ended up at their publisher settings page which provided us snippets of code to insert into our site. We did so and initially survey questions appeared and it seemed to work, however after it asked us a few generic test questions it has refused to serve up another one. On top of that we continue to see a reference to a 'reporting dashboard' as seen [here](https://support.google.com/consumersurveys/answer/2483758?hl=en&ref_topic=2476646). However it is not clear how one goes about accessing this dashboard.

So a couple questions:
1) do we need to be 'accepted' by GCS before we will see a dashboard, and if so how do you access the dashboard?
2) is there a way to ensure that testing survey questions will continue to be provided even though we have not been officially approved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here are things that might be of help.

1) You don't need to be accepted/approved to have access, just be sure to be logged in with the email account you used in signing up. I believe there is an email sent to you after signing up with GCS that contains the link to your reporting dashboard. Once you access the reporting dashboard you'll see that it says "under evaluation". Once your site is approved you will start to serve paid surveys and see the reports in the dashboard.

2) The questions/survey will continue to prompt once you have implemented the GCS code up until you are approved.

You may also want to contact the support team of GCS publishers through this [link](https://www.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/publishers). Just click on the contact us button on the description below "add surveys to your site" button.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Cleia. You are correct, there was an email with the Visit Dashboard link which I promptly forgot about after I clicked on it and continued to look for the dashboard link online. Also the test survey questions repeat when I clear my cache so that's good enough for now.